# Snort rule for HTTP GET and GIF within a URI

Tags: snort

I'm stuck on an Immersive Labs question (4 days now) and I'm banging my head off the keyboard. The question is 'Create a Snort rule that looks for an HTTP method ‘GET’ and contains ‘gif’ in the URL'.

This is what I have written but it's wrong and I can't see why?!:

alert tcp any any > any 80 (content: “GET”; http_method; content:”gif”; http_uri; sid:1000001; rev:01;)

Am I a million miles away? Am I close? Is it the syntax? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on this one. The solution requires a signature that looks for bi-directional traffic I found so yes you were very close

```
alert tcp any any <> any 80 (msg:"test";sid:1000001;content:"GET";http_method;content:"gif";http_uri;)
```